# How to check for duplicate records in excel using POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

below is the code for reading the excel file using poi: which is working fine

```
public class ReadExcelDemo { 
    public static void main(String[] args)  { 
 try {           
     FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("demo.xlsx"));  
     List sheetData = new ArrayList();

    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file); 

    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  ArrayList<Form> vipList = new ArrayList<Form>();
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();   
    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {            
        Row row = rowIterator.next();

        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();   
        List data = new ArrayList();

        while (cellIterator.hasNext())  { 

            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();    

            switch (cell.getCellType())                     {        
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:  System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t"); 
            break;                       
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING: System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");  
            break;     
            }           
        }

    }  


    }
```

Now if excel contains duplicate records I should be able to print a simple error message. How do I do that?

Example:

```
ID    Firstname     Lastname     Address
  1     Ron           wills      Paris
  1     Ron           wills      London
```

Now i want to check the duplicates only for the 3 columns: ID,Firstname and Lastname together. If these columns together contain same data as shown in the above example then it needs to be considered duplicate.

I have a pojo class Form consisting of the id,firstname and lastname with getters

and setters. Each record read is written to the pojo class using the setter methods. Then I am getting the values using getters and adding them to the arraylist object. Now the list object contains all the records. How do I compare them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class ProcessAction extends DispatchAction {

    String dupValue = null;
    ArrayList<String> dupList = new ArrayList<String>();

    private String validateDuplicateRecords(ProcessForm process) {
        String errorMessage = null;

        dupValue = process.getId.trim()+"    "+process.getFirstname().trim()+"    "+process.getLastanme().trim();
        mLogger.debug("order id,ctn,item id: "+dupValue);
        if (dupList.contains(dupValue)){
            mLogger.debug("value not added");
            errorMessage = "Duplicate Record Exists";
        } else {
            dupList.add(dupValue);
        }

        return errorMessage;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to clear the duplicate arraylist. I my case after performing certain tasks like writing the arraylist to a file i am clearing the duplicate arraylist using:

```
dupList.clear();
```

If you don't do this then what happens is when you upload the same data once more even if the records are not duplicate it will say duplicate since the dupList arraylist contains the previous uploaded data.

Answer (score 2):

Throw the data in a set and check contains before every new entry. If you use a HashSet it will be quite quick. You can just pretend everything is Strings for the compare.

```
        Set data = new HashSet();

    while (cellIterator.hasNext())  { 

        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();    
        if(data.contains(cell.getStringCellValue())
            trow new IllegalDataException()
        data.add(cell.getStringCellValue();

        switch (cell.getCellType())                     {        
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:  System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t"); 
        break;                       
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING: System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");  
        break;     
        }           
    }
```

If you need to actually compare the whole row you can create a class with all the fields, and then just override the equals method. Then throw that in a set and compare.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tip. While you loop, add your id (value to check the duplication based on) in a hashmap. if the size of the map did not change, then it is a duplicated record because keys overwrite each other if they already exist. Here's an example from a code of mine:

```
switch(cellType)
{
case 0:
    your_id = cell1.getNumericCellValue();
    mapSize = map.size();

    map.put(your_id, your_id);
    mapSizeAfterPut = map.size();

    if(mapSize == mapSizeAfterPut)
    {
        duplicatedRecordsList.add(index);
    }

    break;
case 1:
    your_id = cell1.getStringCellValue();
    mapSize = map.size();

    map.put(your_id , your_id);
    mapSizeAfterPut = map.size();

    if(mapSize == mapSizeAfterPut) 
    {
        duplicatedRecordsList.add(index);
    }

    break;
default:break;
}
```